# Is there a way to have Netbean's generated PHP Unit tests to adhere to CodeSniffer Zend Standards?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, netbeans-7, phpcodesniffer

I am using Netbeans to generate PHP Unit tests and CodeSniffer doesn't like the template that was generated because it's not Zend standard. How can I have the PHP Unit test templates generate Zend standard templates so it won't throw all those violations?

Answer (score 1):

The skeleton generation is part of the PHPUnit source-code. I think you need to fork the project, then modify the skeleton generation according to your needs and then use your fork.

Comment: Please see your template directory: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/3.6/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Template - Additionally I'd say that stackoverflow is not the best place to search for peers doing that task. Consider to pay the php or phpunit IRC channel a visit or post to the mailinglist. See the phpunit website for support options and ways to help with the project. - You also might consider to wait for some more days and then place a bounty on your question which will raise more awareness. I also added the zend-framework tag to your question.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't looking for anyone to do the job. I'm looking into it myself and seeing how I can do this, fyi. I actually saw that directory, and I was a little surprised because it seems that the test templates do follow the Zend standard, so I'm still investigating.

Comment: I'm not that fluent with the Zend Standard. Probably you can add some skeleton code to your question and mark parts that violate the standard? That might be good for some reference and also for others to leave more room for answers, like giving suggestions / feedback (or even a solution).